# Check if two timestamps are the same day in Ruby

Tags: ruby, date, time

I'm a bit confused between Date, Datetime, and Time in Ruby. What's more, my application is sensitive to timezones, and I'm not sure how to convert between these three while being timezone-robust.

How can I check if two unix timestamps (seconds since epoch) represent the same day? (I don't actually mind if it uses local time or UTC; while I'd prefer local time, as long as it's consistent, I can design around that).

Answer (score 57, accepted):

Using the standard library, convert a Time object to a Date.

```
require 'date'

Time.at(x).to_date === Time.at(y).to_date
```

Date has the [`===`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/date/rdoc/Date.html#method-i-3C-3D-3E) method that will be true if two date objects represent the same day.

Comment: Dates and Times in Ruby are time zone aware. So if you create the Date object using UTC, then yes it will be in UTC. If you create them using a different zone, then they will be in that zone.

Comment: Obviously the best solution for Ruby 1.9. Though, for some reason `Time#to_date` is private method in Ruby 1.8.7.

Comment: Thanks @KL-7. I'm not sure why it was made private in 1.8.7, but it seems like the core team found it useful to expose it as a public method in 1.9.

Comment: @thebackhand timestamps are timezone-neutral, so yes

Comment: Triple equals to represent approximate equality seems a little surprising, but that's what the RDoc says!

Comment: Work great. Great help.

Comment: you can use `.to_datetime`

Comment: @DarlanDieterich: `Time` is already a "date with time". Here we're trying to disregard the time component.

Answer (score 7):

ActiveSupport defines nice [`to_date` method](http://apidock.com/rails/Time/to_date) for `Time` class. That's how it looks like:

```
class Time
  def to_date
    ::Date.new(year, month, day)
  end
end
```

Using it you can compare timestamps like that:

```
Time.at(ts1).to_date === Time.at(ts2).to_date
```

And here is less controversial way without extending `Time` class:

```
t1 = Time.at(ts1) # local time corresponding to given unix timestamp ts1
t2 = Time.at(ts2)
Date.new(t1.year, t1.month, t1.day) === Date.new(t2.year, t2.month, t2.day)
```

Comment: This question is tagged with `Ruby`; I don't think it's fair to assume that he's using Rails.

Comment: Yeah, I'm not using Rails. Also, Time.at(1324196871).to_date == Time.at(1324253810).to_date returns false for me... is it automatically converting the timestamp to localtime for me?

Comment: But he can define this helper method himself. The code is provided. :-)

Comment: In all seriousness, is this considered idiomatic in Ruby? I'm more experienced in Python, where extending classes dynamically is possible, but almost always the wrong approach.

Comment: I personally prefer not to extend classes unless I have to. Extending makes for harder-to-understand code (important when you have new people coming to a project)

Comment: In some cases extending library classes (Object, for example) can make wonders. But for this case this is overkill, IMHO.

Comment: @thebackhand, I updated the answer. For comparing days represented by `Date` objects you should use `===` instead of `==`. Usually it's better to avoid extending base classes, but I'm used to some simple things like `Time#to_date` in Rails and don't understand why we don't have them in standard library. I just pointed out how it's implemented in ActiveSupport, you can do the same without extending `Time` class: `t = Time.at(ts); d = Date.new(t.year, t.month, t.day)`.

Comment: @SergeiTulentsev, extending standard classes might be an overkill for such a simple task, but if you need to do it all over your project having `Time#to_date` looks much better to me than repeating same actions everywhere or moving them into some third place.

Comment: @thebackhand, in fact you should upvote and use solution from @Anurag. It turned out that `date.rb` from standard library already [defines](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.2/libdoc/date/rdoc/Time.html) `to_date` method for `Time` class. At least in Ruby 1.9.

Comment: It is easy to [use ActiveSupport methods in a Ruby script without using Rails](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_support_core_extensions.html).

Answer (score 3):

```
Time.at(ts1).day == Time.at(ts2).day && (ts1 - ts2).abs <= 86400
```

Or

```
t1 = Time.at(ts1)
t2 = Time.at(ts2)
t1.yday == t2.yday && t1.year == t2.year
```

In the first case we make sure that timestamps are no more than day apart (because #day returns day of month and without this additional check Apr 1 would be equal to May 1)

An alternative is to take day of year and make sure that they are of the same year.

These methods work equally well in both 1.8 and 1.9.

Answer (score 2):

We can use `beginning_of_day` of the time and compare them:

`t1.beginning_of_day == t2.beginning_of_day`

This way the timezones won't be affected.